# Android finish() Activity Not working

Tags: android

I got this error in my codes when i use `finish();` "The method finish() is undefined for the type SaveImageTask" . Am I missing some declarations or anything. Can someone please guide me on this.

```
    public class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String> {

            private Context context;
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            boolean bCancelled=false;
            public SaveImageTask(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // MY STUFF
                return null;   
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                pDialog.dismiss();

            }

            OnCancelListener cancelListener=new OnCancelListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0){
                    bCancelled=true;
                    SaveImageTask.this.finish(); // <<----"The method finish() is undefined for the type SaveImageTask"
                }
            };


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use,

```
(Activity(context)).finish();
```

**EDIT:**

Actually you have to cast your context to Activity Context,

then you can use `finish()` method of Activity,

Something like,

```
private Activity context;

public SaveImageTask(Context context) {
                this.context = (Activity)context;
            }
```

now, just

```
context.finish();
```

Comment: I've already pass it on top. Got this error "The method Activity(Context) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){}"

Answer (score 3):

use `SaveImageTask.this.finish();`

Comment: Now I get the error "The method finish() is undefined for the type SaveImageTask"

Comment: that is because `SaveImageTask` is not an activity. Refer to the enclosing activity to your AsyncTask class instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
 OnCancelListener cancelListener=new OnCancelListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0){
                    bCancelled=true;
                    finish(); // <<----"The method finish() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){}"
                }
            };
```

you are creating an `anonymous class` here. Only final variables and methods of the outer class are accessible inside an anonymous class directly. [`Activity` 's `finish`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) is not a final method. What you need to do is reference the 'outer' class, which is an `Activity` and call its `finish()`

`ActivityName.this.finish()`

Note : you cannot make a static call like `ActivityName.finish()` hence the reference of activity's object `this`.