# Tried everything but android finish(); activity not working

Tags: java, android, android-activity

We tried everything to finish a particular activity but failed to do so. The Code runs without any error or warning just cant finish the activity. We tried every solutions in stackoverflow along with other forums. Need a solution with explanation.

[Android finish() Activity Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217871/android-finish-activity-not-working)

[Android finishing activity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131466/android-finishing-activity-not-working)

[android finish activity context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376730/android-finish-activity-context)

```
public void HttpSmsRequest(final String Phone){
        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...";
        pDialog.show();



        Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // jsonParams.put("param1", youParameter);
        jsonParams.put("Phone", Phone);


        //jsonParams.put("rememberMe", "true";

        JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                AppGlobal.host+"PhoneVerification/sendSms",
                new JSONObject(jsonParams),

                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try
                        {
                            Log.v("Success", "success: " + response.toString());
                            //MessageBox.Show(ProfileInfoActivity.this, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response.toString());
                          //  String ID=obj.getString("ID";
                            String Flag=obj.getString("Flag";
                            String Message=obj.getString("Message";



                           // Context context = getApplicationContext();
                           //
                          ///  appPrefs.setUserIdentity(Integer.parseInt(ID));



                            if(Boolean.parseBoolean(Flag))
                            {
                                Intent intent=new Intent(PhoneVerificationActivity.this,ConfirmSms.class);
                                intent.putExtra("PhoneNumber", Phone);
                                //intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                                return;
                                //finishActivity(Activity.RESULT_OK);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(context, ex.getMessage());

                        }

                        // verificationSuccess(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Log.v("Success", "Error: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            MessageBox.Show(PhoneVerificationActivity.this, "Error: " + error.toString());
                            AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll("tag_json_obj";
                        }


                        pDialog.dismiss();

                        //verificationFailed(error);
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map headers = new HashMap();
                if (!Preference.getInstance().getCookie().equals("")
                    headers.put("Cookie", Preference.getInstance().getCookie());
                return headers;
            }

/*@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

Map headers = response.headers;
String cookie = headers.get("Set-Cookie".toString();
Preference.getInstance().saveCookie(cookie);
//  MyApp.get().checkSessionCookie(response.headers);
Log.v("Success", "Response"+response.headers.toString());
return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
}*/
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(myRequest, "tag_json_obj";

    }
```

Comment: Is this code inside an Activity?

Comment: Try this `PhoneVerificationActivity.this.finish();`

Comment: Yes its inside an activity @Mauker

Comment: Tried that one too amy but didnt work @Amy

Comment: is your `ConfirmSms` is starting?

Comment: Yes it starts and we want to finish the PhoneVerificationActivity but when we press the back button it returns to the PhoneVerificationActivity. I've also tried to finish my activity in onPause() and also on onStop() methods but it didn't work.

Comment: Your this piece of code is absolute correct, if your ConfirmSms is starting.
May be the problem is in you previous activity from which PhoneVerificationActivity is called of may be in phoneVerificationActivity. So please your caode throughly

Comment: Yes you were right there was a problem in another activity. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to create a method on your `Activity` that will call `finish()`. And then, call this method from within your `onResponse()`.

Something like:

```
private void killActivity() {
    finish();
}
```

And then, call it here:

```
if(Boolean.parseBoolean(Flag)) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(PhoneVerificationActivity.this,ConfirmSms.class);
    intent.putExtra("PhoneNumber", Phone);
    startActivity(intent);
    killActivity(); // Here.
}
```

> Reason: OP seems to call `finish()` of something else, but giving it a unique-name should ensure right thing's `finish()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked. I tried to vote up your answer but I need 15 reps :/

Answer (score 1):

Check the following in your code

1.Are you extends Activity correctly?

```
Public class YourActivity extends Activity{
  }
```

2.if you extends activity correctly, Finish() will work properly.

```
YourActivity.this.finish();
```

3.if you use Dialogs, you should dismiss the Dialog before finish the activity

```
Dialog.dismiss();
```

Hope may be its helpful.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are transferring big data in intent result then it may not finish activity.
e.g when i am putting byte array on image of big size, finish is not working, when i change image size same code works.