# finish() not working on activity.

Tags: android, activity-finish

I tried the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514499/tried-everything-but-android-finish-activity-not-working), but I cannot get an activity to finish.

Here is the code:

```
  private void myMethod() {
    startActivity(startNewActivityOpen2);
    GlobalVars.questionHolders = null;  //is being called.  
    finish();
    amTransitioning = true;
  }
```

Calling Activity was started with these flags:

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

I tried

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

but this didn't work.

I can see that finish is getting called.  My logcat is saying:

> Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{426f37f8 u0 com.assistek.ediary/.PRO_GridOther t5569 f}

The activity continues along its merry way without finishing and I am getting a null pointer error because a singleton's value is getting cleared.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Generally you don't need to manually call `finish()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finish(); does not terminate the activity the way you think it continue executing any code called after finish() you should write a "return;" after finish to avoid any code execution

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want `amTransitioning` to be `true`, so you have to call it before finishing the `Activity`.

> I can see that finish is getting called. My logcat is saying:

Are you finishing the `Activity` in other method or something? If you do so that's the message on `Logcat`. If you want to avoid this message, just before finishing add `YOURACTIVITY.isFinishing()` if it's true don't finish, otherwise finish().